# siunitx S-column in table: can I combine scientific notation and decimal numbers in one column?

Tags: tables, formatting, siunitx

I have a table with values exported from a statistics software, where the values are formatted like this (see example below):

Some (very small ones) are in scientific notation, some are in "normal" decimal notation.

```
\begin{tabular}{r}
3,158722 \\
-0,00061 \\
6,28E-05 \\
0,000303 \\
1,67E-04 \\
0,000175 \\
-0,00017 \\
0,000025 \\
-0,00012 \\
-7,7E-05 \\
-0,00042 \\
-0,0005 \\
0,128871 \\
-0,00689 \\
0,004255 \\
-0,00245 \\
0,010475 \\
0,007083 \\
0,000852 \\
0,004583 \\
-0,00042 \\
0,002032 \\
-0,00111 \\
0,000556 \\
12,53887 \\
0,0024 \\
-0,00387 \\
0,002836 \\
-0,00052 \\
-0,00022 \\
5,41E-05 \\
-0,00063 \\
3,17E-04 \\
0,000187 \\
-0,08153 \\
-0,07881 \\
0,316826 \\
0,001066 \\
0,009783 \\
-0,02701 \\
0,006054 \\
0,004167 \\
\end{tabular}%
```

- How can I define a number formatting that makes sense?
- Is it possible with `siunitx`to combine decimal and scientific notation in one column?
  If yes, how can I define when the scientific notation is used and when not?

Comment: Do you have the input in the form you list above (i.e. with the difference between scientific and 'plain' numbers built-in)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. The output in the example is exactly as I get it from the statistics software - partly "plain" and partly scientific notation.  It seems that the number of characters per line is limited, so the applications chooses the "best" way to display the number. However, thanks to your question, I've just found (I forgot) that I could influence that format and make it consistens (purely decimal or scientific), if it would make things easier for `siunitx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `siunitx` is good at aligning a series of numbers in a similar format, it is less good for this type of mixed input. My initial thought would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format = -1.6e1, table-align-exponent = false]}
    3,158722 \\
    -0,00061 \\
    6,28E-05 \\
    0,000303 \\
    1,67E-04 \\
    0,000175 \\
    -0,00017 \\
    0,000025 \\
    -0,00012 \\
    -7,7E-05 \\
    -0,00042 \\
    -0,0005 \\
    0,128871 \\
    -0,00689 \\
    0,004255 \\
    -0,00245 \\
    0,010475 \\
    0,007083 \\
    0,000852 \\
    0,004583 \\
    -0,00042 \\
    0,002032 \\
    -0,00111 \\
    0,000556 \\
    12,53887 \\
    0,0024 \\
    -0,00387 \\
    0,002836 \\
    -0,00052 \\
    -0,00022 \\
    5,41E-05 \\
    -0,00063 \\
    3,17E-04 \\
    0,000187 \\
    -0,08153 \\
    -0,07881 \\
    0,316826 \\
    0,001066 \\
    0,009783 \\
    -0,02701 \\
    0,006054 \\
    0,004167 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

but this will have too much space on the right margin. Perhaps a new option is needed in `siunitx` to handle this case.

One alternative approach is to use a strategy similar to the `dcolumn` package, making both `,` and `E` active in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newbox\tabboxa
\newbox\tabboxb
\newcommand*\tabalignstart{%
  \setbox\tabboxa=\hbox{$-1$}%
    \setbox\tabboxa=\hbox to \wd\tabboxa
      \bgroup
        $
        \lccode`\~=`\,\relax
        \mathcode`\,="8000%
        \lowercase{\def~}%
          {%
              $%
            \egroup
            \setbox\tabboxb=\hbox
              \bgroup
                $
                \lccode`\~=`\E\relax
                \mathcode`\E="8000%
                \lowercase{\def~}####1####2####3%
                  {\times 10^{####1####3}}%
                  .
          }%
        \hfill
}
\newcommand*\tabalignstop{%
    $
    \hfil
  \egroup
  \box\tabboxa
  \box\tabboxb
}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\tabalignstart}l<{\tabalignstop}}
    3,158722 \\
    -0,00061 \\
    6,28E-05 \\
    0,000303 \\
    1,67E-04 \\
    0,000175 \\
    -0,00017 \\
    0,000025 \\
    -0,00012 \\
    -7,7E-05 \\
    -0,00042 \\
    -0,0005 \\
    0,128871 \\
    -0,00689 \\
    0,004255 \\
    -0,00245 \\
    0,010475 \\
    0,007083 \\
    0,000852 \\
    0,004583 \\
    -0,00042 \\
    0,002032 \\
    -0,00111 \\
    0,000556 \\
    12,53887 \\
    0,0024 \\
    -0,00387 \\
    0,002836 \\
    -0,00052 \\
    -0,00022 \\
    5,41E-05 \\
    -0,00063 \\
    3,17E-04 \\
    0,000187 \\
    -0,08153 \\
    -0,07881 \\
    0,316826 \\
    0,001066 \\
    0,009783 \\
    -0,02701 \\
    0,006054 \\
    0,004167 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

Of course, the problem then is that there are no digit separators.